# Only in Chrome, the inner contents of DIV tag are overflowing when body class is added

Tags: jquery, css, drupal-7

**PROBLEM:**

This problem is only occurring in Chrome.

When I use jQuery to add a class to the body tag, then there is a DIV tag on the page that changes its style when the new class is added to the body, but the inner content is overflowing. When I refresh the page, everything fits together the way it should.

I have tested this in IE and Firefox, and it works fine in both browsers without any problems.

**DESCRIPTION:**

I am using jQuery to add a class to the body:

```
$(document).load(function() {
  if (UNDER_CERTAIN_CONDITIONS) {
    $('body').addClass('some-new-class');
  }
});
```

Then I have a stylesheet that adjusts the page accordingly:

```
body.some-new-class div.requires-special-styling {
  /* ... */
}
```

Note: I am using Drupal 7 and an overridden version of the Bartik theme, in case that helps solve the issue.

Comment: can you include your CSS or a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: what do you mean the inner content is overflowing?

Comment: So, if I have a paragraph inside the DIV tag, then the paragraph will be wider than the DIV tag, overlapping it on the right side. If the paragraph had a border you would see the border stretch past the boundary of the DIV tag on the right. When I refresh the page, the paragraph fits inside the DIV tag the way I would expect it to. I think there is a timing issue going on with JavaScript, because everything works on the second page refresh, but what event is the script competing with?